# Can the blank space that is colored when a text with a background in UITextView moves to the next line be prevented?

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

As seen in the image below, extra spaces occur when the text goes to the bottom line. Can I prevent these from occurring?

[image: UITextView AttributedString Image]

My code:

```swift
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vel suscipit ex. Nulla facilisi. Aenean rutrum auctor mauris eu euismod."
        
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .right
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
        
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attributes)
        
        let redRange = (str as NSString).range(of: "Lorem ipsum")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: redRange)
        let greenRange = (str as NSString).range(of: "Aenean rutrum auctor mauris eu euismod")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: greenRange)
        
        attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 22)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.count))
        
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a result like the UILabel.

[image: UILabel AttributedString Image]

Comment: I copy/pasted your code but in my case it's working fine. What version of iOS are you using on the device? Did you set some attributes on the TextView in the storyboard's attribute inspector?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I added UITextView and UILabel to the Main.storyboard and gave the Constraint values. The rest of my code can be found in the attached file. [ViewController.swift](https://file.io/2o00Rr3UlR05)

Comment: I don't know if this helps - I ran the code on two iPhones, one running iOS 16.3 and one running iOS 15.7. The former doesn't have the "extra spaces", the latter does.

Comment: Thank you again, I think the problem has been fixed in newer versions. However, I need it for all devices running iOS 12 and above.

Comment: I think you should implement custom NSLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

In InterfaceBuilder, select a TextView and go to Attributes Inspector -> Text Layout. Expected behavior comes with 'TextKit2', By default 'TextKit2' is set when the value is set to 'default'.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem has been fixed in newer versions. However, I need it for all devices running iOS 12 and above. (Xcode 14 has the option but Xcode 13 does not.)